# abrir dos ventanas modal

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un modal y dentro del modal tengo un botón para abrir otro modal. mi problema esta que cuando abro el segundo modal y salgo, el primer modal esta abierto pero cuando hago Scroll lo hace a la pagina principal y no al modal como puedo hacer que el Scroll lo haga en el modal y no en la pagina principal.

este es mi modal

```
<!-- Vertical form modal -->
<div id="recibirequipoModal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title">Recepcion De Equipos Para Reparar</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>


<div class="modal-body">

   <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label> &nbsp; </label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <button type="button" id="addcli_button" onclick="limpiar()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#clienteModal" class="btn bg-primary-400 btn-labeled btn-labeled-left"><b><i class="icon-user-plus"></i></b>Nuevo</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /vertical form modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade el siguiente código en CSS.

`.modal { overflow: auto !important; }`

Con esto se corrige tu error. Lo he testeado y me funcionó sin problemas.

[Ejemplo en JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zc8xy3b/4/)